# Making an application run in multiple zones

Tags: .net

I am currently revising for exam 70-536. Is there a sample of how to configure an application to run in multiple environments? E.g. intranet and internet.

I can't find a good code sample for this. Anyone have one?

Answer (score 1):

I think these exam questions are about [CAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302330.aspx). Make sure you understand the concept behind it. You will have to know how to configure the policies for your app, etc.